# data not being updated in aws when using kinesis data stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis

Im trying to implement kinesis data streams into my react native application using amplify.
I have followed the steps as stated in the official documentation, but no data is being updated when I check aws page.

This is my code

```
Analytics.addPluggable(new AWSKinesisProvider())
Analytics.configure({
    AWSKinesis: {

        // OPTIONAL -  Amazon Kinesis service region
        region: 'us-east-2',

        // OPTIONAL - The buffer size for events in number of items.
        bufferSize: 1000,

        // OPTIONAL - The number of events to be deleted from the buffer when flushed.
        flushSize: 100,

        // OPTIONAL - The interval in milliseconds to perform a buffer check and flush if necessary.
        flushInterval: 5000, // 5s

        // OPTIONAL - The limit for failed recording retries.
        resendLimit: 5
    } 
})

Analytics.record({
 data: { 
  mydata:"new data"
 },
 streamName: '*myStreamName*'
 }, 'AWSKinesis');
```

After executing this is how my console from debugger looks like this

```
 LOG  [DEBUG] 31:18.860 Credentials - getting credentials
 LOG  [DEBUG] 31:18.862 Credentials - picking up credentials
 LOG  [DEBUG] 31:18.863 Credentials - getting new cred promise
 LOG  [DEBUG] 31:18.866 Credentials - checking if credentials exists and not expired
 LOG  [DEBUG] 31:18.868 Credentials - are these credentials expired? {"accessKeyId": "****", "authenticated": true, "expiration": 2020-11-03T11:29:53.000Z, "identityId": "****", "secretAccessKey": "****", "sessionToken": "****"}
 LOG  [DEBUG] 31:18.871 Credentials - credentials not changed and not expired, directly return
 LOG  [DEBUG] 31:18.905 AWSKinesisProvider - set credentials for analytics undefined
 LOG  [DEBUG] 31:20.576 AWSKinesisProvider - init clients
 LOG  [DEBUG] 31:20.579 AWSKinesisProvider - initialize kinesis with credentials {"accessKeyId": "****", "authenticated": true, "identityId": "****", "secretAccessKey": "****", "sessionToken": "****"}
 LOG  [DEBUG] 31:20.624 AWSKinesisProvider - putting records to kinesis with records [{"Data": [123, 34, 109, 121, 100, 97, 116, 97, 34, 58, 34, 104, 101, 108, 108, 
111, 32, 105, 109, 32, 110, 101, 119, 32, 104, 101, 114, 101, 34, 125], "PartitionKey": "partition-us-east-2:****"}]
 LOG  [DEBUG] 31:22.311 AWSKinesisProvider - Upload records to stream *myStreamName*
```